# How can I JOIN a table with the result of a UNION in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables in an Oracle database. `FooDBflights`, `FooDB1` and `FooDB2`.

I use the "with" operator to create simpler version of these tables named, `FLIGHTS`, `MESSAGES1` and `MESSAGES2`.

I want to make a select statement that returns one table. `FLIGHTS` joined with the union of `MESSAGES1` and `MESSAGES2`

Here is my SQL statement.

```
WITH FLIGHTS AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id,ARCADDR,CALLSIGN,trunc(FIRSTTIMEENTRY)
    AS DOE FROM FooDBflights
    WHERE FIRSTTIMEENTRY IS NOT null),
MESSAGES1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT flightID,AIRCRAFTADDRESS,trunc(SYS_DATETIME)
    FROM FooDB1
    WHERE AIRCRAFTADDRESS!=' ' ),
MESSAGES2 AS ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT flightID,AIRCRAFTADDRESS,trunc(SYS_DATETIME)
    FROM FooDB2
    WHERE AIRCRAFTADDRESS!=' ' )

SELECT a.*,b.*,substr(b.AIRCRAFTADDRESS, 3)
FROM FLIGHTS a
    LEFT JOIN MESSAGES1 b
    ON a.callsign=trim(b.flightid)
    AND trim(a.arcaddr)=substr(UPPER (b.AIRCRAFTADDRESS), 3)
```

This query returns `FLIGHTS` and `MESSAGES1` joined perfectly, but I can't figure out how to make the union between `MESSAGES1` and `MESSAGES2`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the easiest to perform the union in the `with` clause:

Instead of

```
MESSAGES1 AS ...
MESSAGES2 AS ...
```

Do:

```
MESSAGES AS (
    SELECT flightID,AIRCRAFTADDRESS,trunc(SYS_DATETIME) AS DT
    FROM FooDB1
    WHERE AIRCRAFTADDRESS!=' '
    UNION 
    SELECT flightID,AIRCRAFTADDRESS,trunc(SYS_DATETIME)
    FROM FooDB2
    WHERE AIRCRAFTADDRESS!=' ' )
```

... and reference that one in our main `SELECT` query.

Note that `DISTINCT` is not needed once you do `UNION`.

#### Remark

Using `trim()` in your join conditions could make the query slow when there is a lot of data: the database engine cannot benefit from indexes. It would be better to have foreign keys, and enforce those as database constraints. Then `trim` will not be necessary.

Also `substr()` and `upper()` will potentially have a negative effect on performance. Consider splitting the field `AIRCRAFTADDRESS` into two in the table itself, and make sure the text is already in uppercase on insertion.

Comment: I'd rather say: Note that DISTINCT is not needed once you do `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks this works. Good advice on the performance as well. I'll look into if it is possible to make these adjustments